# ReactiveUI WhenActivated not firing

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I'm trying to use the following code as a safe way to call an async service from within the constructor of my viewmodel as suggested in [this](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/1351) post.  Problem is, nothing from within the body of the `this.WhenActivated` ever fires, any ideas why?

here is my code:

```
class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject, ISupportsActivation, IMainViewModel
{
    private IDataService _dataService;

    private Part _part;

    public Part MyPart
    {
        get { return _part; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _part, value); }
    }

    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;

        this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
        {
            _dataService.GetPart("9176900515")
                .ToObservable()
                .Subscribe(
                    result => { MyPart = result; },
                    exception => { LogMe.Log<string>(exception.Message); }
                )
                .DisposeWith(disposables);
        });
    }

    private readonly ViewModelActivator activator = new ViewModelActivator();
    ViewModelActivator ISupportsActivation.Activator
    {
        get { return activator; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

To make `WhenActivated` work inside a view model, the view model has to be the `ViewModel` of a view that implements `IViewFor<MainViewModel>`.

`MainViewModel`'s `WhenActivated` will then be called by the view's `WhenActvated`.

**Update:**

This is done in WPF, but it's supported on all platforms (WPF, UWP, Xamarin).

The view implements `IViewFor<TViewModel>`. By best practices the `ViewModel` property is a `DependencyProperty` (or `BindableProperty` in Xam.Forms).

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IViewFor<MainViewModel>
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
        // This will be called
    });
    }

    public MainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get => (MainViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty);
        set => SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ViewModel), typeof(MainViewModel), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get => ViewModel;
        set => ViewModel = value as MainViewModel;
    }
}
```

The `WhenActivated` in the VM will now be called when `WhenActivated` is called in the view.

```
class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject, ISupportsActivation
{
    public ViewModelActivator Activator => _activator;
    private ViewModelActivator _activator = new ViewModelActivator();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
            // This will be called
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this only for WPF apps?  This [<link>](https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/binding/windows-presentation-framework.html) only mentions WPF and I can't get it to work. Too much boilerplate causing too many new red squigglies.  I can't find a full example anywhere.

Comment: Hi, in my scenario, `WhenActivated` never fires in the VM, only in the view.

Answer (score 1):

### Implementing the `ViewModel`

For one, the `WhenActivated` pattern is described here: https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/when-activated/

> `WhenActivated` is a way to track disposables. Besides that, it can be used to defer the setup of a `ViewModel` until it's truly required. `WhenActivated` also gives us an ability to start or stop reacting to hot observables, like a background task that periodically pings a network endpoint or an observable updating users current location. Moreover, one can use `WhenActivated` to trigger startup logic when the `ViewModel` comes on stage.

That part of the pattern seems already done right in the question.

### Implementing the View

For your `ViewModel` to be activated, you have to fully follow a specific pattern which is provided in https://reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/#create-views

Here are the key areas:

```
public partial class MainWindow : IViewFor<AppViewModel>
{
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ViewModel.
    // This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel",
            typeof(AppViewModel), typeof(MainWindow),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new AppViewModel();

    // ....
    }

    // ....

    // Our main view model instance.
    public AppViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get => (AppViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty);
        set => SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);
    }

    // This is required by the interface IViewFor, you always just set it to use the
    // main ViewModel property. Note on XAML based platforms we have a control called
    // ReactiveUserControl that abstracts this.
    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get => ViewModel;
        set => ViewModel = (AppViewModel)value;
    }
}
```

Notice that the framework will notice the link from that specific `MainWindow` instance to that specific `AppViewModel` instance when the `ViewModel` setter is called:

```
ViewModel = new AppViewModel();
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Setting the `ViewModel` doesn't trigger activation.

Comment: Vague question yields vague answer. Perhaps sharing your code on a gist may help someone help you. (I'm not using ReactiveUI at the moment, now on C++/PCL/OpenCV/C/Linux, might use ReactiveUI again in 6-12 months.)

Comment: I've found my answer. We need to call `this.WhenActivated(() => {  })` from the constructor.